# R How to subset a dataframe with a for loop through a column

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I want to create a series of data frames that are subsets of a main dataframe based upon the values in a particular factored column.

Below is my data and code:

```
>max_value_found

   Group  Mileage    HiLo 
1  car        808    Hi     
2  train   162993    Lo 
3  car      19386    Hi     
4  walk       231    Lo 



>levels(max_value_found$group)

[1] "car"       "train"     "bike"      "walk"

>for(i in levels(max_value_found$group))
+{  x=paste(i,"_max_value",sep="")
+   x
+   x <-subset(max_value_found, max_value_found$group==i)
+}

>car_max_value

Error: object 'car_max_value' not found
```

I don't get an error but I don't get any new data frames either, as far as I can tell using ls().

What I'm trying to do is have R loop through the list of levels and paste the level name in the resulting dataframe name and use that same level to subset the main dataframe for the subset's dataframe contents.

I could have just manually written out the individual subset statements but would like to know how to do this for the future.

I have similar code working for looping through the same column to generate a series of histograms but this is stumping me.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Probably you could start with `split(max_value_found, max_value_found$group)`

Comment: Ok I didn't know about split command, so thank you for that. I'm also looking for it to provide the level as part of the resulting dataframe.

Comment: What do you mean? You have the levels in the `group` column and also in the name of the data frame

Comment: But I don't think they are actually being created. When I do a ls() command after the for loop is finished, the new data frames are not listed.  And when I do a ls() inside the loop they do not appear there either. So its a strange case of the for loop is not failing but nor am I getting the results I'm looking for. Thanks

Comment: What loop? You don't need to put `split` within the loop. Also, of course they are not present in the global environment. `split` returns a list which you can save somewhere. The real question is do you *really* need to create lots of data frames and spam your global environment or can you keep them in that list?

Comment: So I'd like them to be in my global environment. Again, I don't think they are being created but if they were, would I do something like write.csv each of the subset data frames as they are being created and then read them into the global environment?

Comment: No. You can just do `list2env(split(max_value_found, max_value_found$group), .GlobalEnv)` (without any loop), then try `car`, for example. Though this is very not recommended to do you usually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As David pointed out in the comments:

```
max_value_found <- data.frame(Group = c("car", "train", "car", "walk"),
                              Mileage = c(808, 162993, 19386, 231), 
                              HiLo = c("Hi", "Lo", "Hi", "Lo")) 


> list1 <- split(max_value_found, max_value_found$Group)
> list1 
$car   
Group Mileage HiLo 
1   car     808   Hi 
3   car   19386   Hi

$train   
Group Mileage HiLo 
2 train  162993   Lo

$walk   
Group Mileage HiLo 
4  walk     231   Lo
```

**Edit**: to set these free into the global environment again use David's code:

```
> list2env(list1, .GlobalEnv)
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
> ls()
[1] "car"             "list1"           "max_value_found" "train"          
[5] "walk"           
> str(car)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Group  : Factor w/ 3 levels "car","train",..: 1 1
 $ Mileage: num  808 19386
 $ HiLo   : Factor w/ 2 levels "Hi","Lo": 1 1
> str(train)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Group  : Factor w/ 3 levels "car","train",..: 2
 $ Mileage: num 162993
 $ HiLo   : Factor w/ 2 levels "Hi","Lo": 2
> car
  Group Mileage HiLo
1   car     808   Hi
3   car   19386   Hi
> train
  Group Mileage HiLo
2 train  162993   Lo
```

I don't think that this is a good move though. You are better off accessing the data frames from the list i.e. `list1$car` or `list1[["car"]]`.

Comment: And what type of list `split(max_value_found, max_value_found$Group)` gives you? Isn't it already named?

Comment: You can keep the `split` answer so the question will be answered.

Comment: Ok I get it, the list1 is an array of data frames. Is there a way to split them into separate data frames? aside from that I think that will work just fine. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I think I need to read up more on environments but this definitely solves my problem.